# Removing shipping address in paypal with rest api

Tags: rest, paypal, shopping-cart

hi i have integrated paypal pg to my website,i have successfully redirected to payment page but i need to Remove shipping address in  paypal  with rest api.

can any give me suggestion to remove

if not possible i am passing shipping address info but am getting null pointer exception is

```
SEVERE: Error code : 400 with response :
{"name":"UNKNOWN_ERROR","message":"An unknown error has occurred","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#UNKNOWN_ERROR","debug_id":"739a5c9de72f5"}
```

can any one help me to over come this problem

Answer (score 0):

I pulled the log based on the debug ID you provided.

It seems the error triggered was an error code of 10729.

Based on the [API Error and Warning Codes](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/), 10729 means that the "state" in your shipping address which you passed to PayPal in SetExpressCheckout request is missing.

Just include the "state" in your shipping address should rectify this issue.